# Can't create stored procedure with reference to table in other database

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, stored-procedures

I have some databases on Azure SQL v12. One is named `GM_STAGE` and one `STRAT_CMS`.

I am trying to add this stored procedure to `STRAT_CMS`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GM_STAGE_FILE_LOAD_STS_GET]
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT *
    FROM [GM_STAGE].[dbo].[FILE_LOAD_STATUS]
```

END

I am getting this error which I don't understand because the database clearly exists.

> Reference to database and/or server name in 'GM_STAGE.dbo.FILE_LOAD_STATUS' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

[image]

Why can't I create this stored procedure?

Comment: what version of sql server are you using and what is the database's compatibility level? `select @@version, compatibility_level from sys.databases where name in ('gm_stage','gm_data_repo');`

Comment: You can't do cross database queries in Azure.

Comment: @SqlZim Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8 
 Dec  5 2016 21:15:30 
 Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Comment: @SeanLange You can now: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/querying-remote-databases-in-azure-sql-db/

Comment: @DavidTunnell I just found that too. I didn't know they fixed that.

Comment: @SqlZim The query you suggest returned 2 columns with no rows.

Comment: In addition the Richards link below here is another good write up for how to accomplish this. http://www.scarydba.com/2016/03/21/cross-database-queries-in-azure-sql-database/

Comment: There are [more than a dozen existing questions with this error message](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+%22Reference+to+database+and%2For+server+name%22). Did you search and see if any of these might be relevant to your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Cross database queries are supported in Azure SQL v12. Make sure that both databases you are using are up to date.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/querying-remote-databases-in-azure-sql-db/